# reading excel sheet from assets folder in android

Tags: android, sqlite

> How to read data in excel-sheet in assets folder and retrieve database?
>   'I have an excel sheet where my different tables of database is written and i want to read the  excel sheet so to store it in database and then want to retrieve database

public class ReadFileAssetsActivity extends ActionBarActivity
         {

```
private Button btnReadExcel1;
AssetManager assetManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnReadExcel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadExcel1);

    btnReadExcel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btnReadExcel1) 

                readExcelFileFromAssets();
        }
    }); {


    assetManager = getAssets();

    }


}

public void readExcelFileFromAssets() {

    try {
        // Creating Input Stream

         File file = new File( "file:\\assets\\winthrop-mobile-data-test-records.xls");




       FileInputStream myInput = new
          FileInputStream(file)//





      //            InputStream myInput;



        // myInput = assetManager.open("main table.xlsx");



       // Create a POIFSFileSystem object


        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

        // Create a workbook using the File System

        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);


           /** We now need something to iterate through the cells. 
   **/
          Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();


         while (rowIter.hasNext()) {

            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();


            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();


            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {

                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();

                Log.e("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " + myCell.toString()
                        + " Index :" + myCell.getColumnIndex());

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cell Value: 

           " +  // myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return;
}'
```

Comment: `// myInput = assetManager.open("main table.xlsx");`. That is the way to go. Why did you try and not use it?

Comment: You did not tell is the file being in assets is the problem. Could you handle all if it was on the file system?

Comment: `to store it in database and then want to retrieve database`. ????? Please elaborate.

Comment: no i want to show it on the log cat when i run it do not display on log

Comment: i have an excel file of database that i want to use in  my project and after that i have to use that database to retrieve some data and show it on the UI

Comment: Your not to the point comments do not bring this further.

Comment: can you just answer me how to read excel file in assets folder and show the data in logcat

Comment: The answer is in my first comment. But it seems that you did not take that serious.

Comment: now i have one more problem with this in logcat it shows office xml file exception.data appears to be in office 2007+xml.you need to call different part of Poi to process this data(XSSF instead of HSSF).Can you please help me into this.i do not know how to use XSSF